# Elasticsearch query: posts of frieds of friends

Tags: elasticsearch

How should be query in Elasticsearch to extract posts of friends, and friends of friends?

- friends{id, user_id, friend_id}
- posts{id, title, content, owner_id}

Comment: Each person has one friends?

Comment: no, one person can have or not friends at all

Comment: Can person have multiple friends?

Comment: yes, person can have friends from zero to total users in system minus one

Comment: So friends_id it's array?

Comment: no, you can have multiple insertion in friends {user_id: 3, friend_id: 4}, {user_id: 3, friend_id: 7}

Answer (score 0):

Look at the next query's:

```
GET indexName/posts/_search
{
"query": {
    "match":{
           "Owner_id":friendId
     }
 }
}

GET indexName/friends/_search
{
 "query": {
   "match": {
     "friend_id": personId
   }
}
```

}

Comment: I consume that posts and friends it's two types

Comment: so, do you suggest to make 2 queries?